# Tableview simple display value

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am a stduent and very beginner of swift3. In here, I just want to display "First","Second","Third" in the tableview and it does not look good.

The tutorial from the youtube is swift2 and I try to convert into swift3. I think the problem is related to code:

```
let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

I try hard to search like https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2016/09/14/evolving-to-swift-3/ but I dont know what happen. The Xcode cannot detect any error of the code and it can run. The tableview in iphone simulator is empty or whole screen is black.

I use the navigation controller to implement it. The class in viewcontoller and iderntifer in table view cell are well set in the root view contoller. Please help me. Thanks.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var Array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Array = ["First","Second","Third"]

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Array.count
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let Cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    Cell.textLabel?.text = Array[indexPath.row]

    return Cell
}
```

}

[image]

Result in console:

```
2016-10-24 01:10:38.111399 TableApp[27276:2609723] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 01:10:38.114012 TableApp[27276:2609723] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 01:10:38.122822 TableApp[27276:2609719] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 01:10:38.138706 TableApp[27276:2609660] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-24 01:10:38.200 TableApp[27276:2609660] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UITableView.m:8035
2016-10-24 01:10:38.203 TableApp[27276:2609660] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView (<UITableView: 0x7fbac906bc00; frame = (0 0; 375 667); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x61000004e400>; layer = <CALayer: 0x610000235ce0>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {375, 132}>) failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource (<TableApp.GetStringViewController: 0x7fbac8d06180>)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fab034b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c9dc21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fab4442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010c572edd -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010d429ff2 -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 222
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010d435c10 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 860
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d435e07 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d409871 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d43f189 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d4259e3 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d38d344 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112875cdc -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001128697a0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000011286961e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001127f762c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112824713 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000112825083 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa54e17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa54d87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa394b6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 454
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010d2c2db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010d2c8f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  TableApp                            0x000000010c3fb5bf main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001109da68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole exception description? Just copy the stack trace from console instead of a screenshot and edit your answer with that details.

Comment: In your storyboard, does your tableview contain a cell with "Cell" as reuseIdentifier?

Comment: @alexburtnik Updated

Comment: @MarieDm I have already put the iderntifer "Cell" in table view cell

Comment: The issue is that your cell for row is returning nil instead of a cell. Let's find out why exactly. So you're using storyboards with a table view and you've set reuse identifier there and you're not using any custom classes for your cells, right?

Comment: @alexburtnik Yes.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAt` and check if it's called at all.

Comment: You dont need to touch your  storyboard at all...just create another project.go to view controller .paste the code and run the project everything should work....note you dont need to set anything on storyboard.....everything done programmatically.code will automatically create tableView for you...cheers

Comment: just updated my screencast. take a look .you can  everything clearly and  dont forgot to give a tick and up vote...

Comment: @Joe Sorry that I am just starting up with swift3 project in 2days... how can i contact you if i got questions and if you dont mind..

Comment: no worries..if you wanna contact me....the easiest way save this page into your desktop.when ever you need help.just give me a buzz with your new post link...we take it from there and dont forgot to give me an up vote.stackOverflow community all about help each other professionally...cheers

Comment: Just a little side note: Array is probably not the best name for a variable.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This code:** Code tested in Swift 3.

**Note:** As you mentioned you just started programming Swift 3.I created a tableView programmatically. Just,copy below code and paste in to your viewController.run the project...

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let MyArray: NSArray = ["First","Second","Third"]
    private var myTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Status Bar 
    let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height 

    // View 
    let displayWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width
    let displayHeight: CGFloat = self.view.frame.height

    // TableView 
    myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: displayWidth, height: displayHeight - barHeight))

    // Cell 
    myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")

    // DataSource 
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    // Delegate 
    myTableView.delegate = self

    // View 
    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Num: \(indexPath.row)")
    print("Value: \(MyArray[indexPath.row])")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return MyArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) 

    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(MyArray[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
 }

}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I  dont know why cannot run it. I start a new project and copy the code and set the reuseIdentifier as "MyCell". No error detected.  The tableview in iphone simulator is empty. And concole shows something like before.