# Tableviewcontroller does not show cells

Tags: swift, tableview

I created table in storyborad. But i inialize it from code. The problem is: when i inialize it from code it does not show cell, my cells are statyc

[image]

this my code for tableview controller:

```
class AutorizedProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.backgroundView=UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bg_profile"))
    //tableView.backgroundColor=UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 69/255, green: 69/255, blue: 69/255, alpha: 0.3)
    tableView.tableFooterView=UIView()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 7
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        return 250
    }
    else{
        return 50
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

and this is how i inialize it from code:

```
if (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).currentcookie[HTTPCookiePropertyKey.value] != nil{
            let menuTable=AutorizedProfileTableViewController().self
            let size=UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            menuTable.view.frame=CGRect(x: size.width-(size.width*3/4), y: 0, width: size.width*3/4, height: size.height)
            profile.addSubview(menuTable.view)
        }else{
            let menuTable=NoAutorizedProfileTableViewController()
            let size=UIScreen.main.bounds.size
            menuTable.view.frame=CGRect(x: size.width-(size.width*3/4), y: 0, width: size.width*3/4, height: size.height)
            profile.addSubview(menuTable.view)
        }
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(profile)
        menuOpen=menuOpen ? false : true
        if menuOpen{
            self.navigationController?.view.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
            self.navigationController?.view.bringSubview(toFront: profile)
        }
        else{
            self.navigationController?.view.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            profile.removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Whats is problem, why i can not see my cells?

Comment: Don't you get an error/warning about missing `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? An since the controller is designed in storyboard, the default initializer `AutorizedProfileTableViewController()` never returns the object in storyboard.

Comment: You missing your cell method cellForRowAt ? check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205397/ios-swift3-tableview-simple-display-value/40206096#40206096

Answer (score 0):

You missed

```
 self.tableview.delegate = self
 self.tableview.datasource = self
```

under viewDidLoad

Comment: No, `UITableViewController` sets delegate and datasource implicitly.

Comment: mmm, not in the AutorizedProfileTableViewController but add it in the second piece of code